# Will 2 600mAh batteries give me the same usage level as one 1200mAh?

Tags: batteries

I am considering obtaining a pair (2) 3.2V AA Lithium Phosphate batteries rated at 600mAh for a project that needs to operate at 3.7v/1.8ohm at peak times and next to nothing the rest. Obviously the mAh significantly impacts on the usage time but would running two 600mAh batteries give me a similar usage time as a single 1200mAh might?

In other words does twice as many cells give me twice the mAh?

Comment: Is your plan to run the two 3.2V batteries in series to get a 6.4V battery, then use some sort of DC-DC converter to reach 3.7V? If that is the plan, then the calculation is more complex.

Comment: To be honest I had not entirely thought about that yet. I was thinking that a variable voltage regulator might be a good idea. I have also started to think that parallel connection and some sort of capacitor so I can get 25 seconds of 3.7v out of the 3.2v might give me better life expectancy between charges. I am really not all that sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If connected in parallel, two 3.2V 600mAh cells will give you a 3.2V 1200mAh battery.  If connected in series, you will end up with a 6.4V 600mAh battery.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I am amazed at how much I have forgotten since I was a teenager. Thank you.